# Facebook Audience framework showing test ads in live app

Tags: ios, facebook-audience-network

i have integrated FB Audience Framework to display ads in my app.
It is working fine in testing but in live app it's also showing test ads not live ads.

Is there any setting need to enable in console for live app ?

Comment: May be you'll have to make fb app live from fb developer settings or it may have two different keys for test and live.

Comment: No, it's now related to fb developer setting.

Comment: have you tried setting your app live in FB developer console?

Comment: Yes, But suppose my placement id  = 246516121564623_12245475456456.

 i need only video ads.so, i change id to VID_HD_16_9_15S_LINK#246516121564623_12245475456456

So, is this the reason behind this test ads in live app?